# Chrome: disable omnibox dropdown

Tags: google-chrome

In Chrome, when you start typing in the omnibox, it shows a dropdown with some of your past search queries and visited URLs.

I don't want this dropdown to show up *at all*.

**This question is not:**

- How to disable omnibox autocomplete (therefore the answer is not "disable the "Use prediction service to ..." settings in Chrome" -- I already did that)
- How to delete a single entry from the omnibox dropdown (therefore the answer is not "highlight an entry in the omnibox and press Shift+Delete")

Also, the answer is not "delete your browsing history", because (a) I want my browsing history to be available in chrome://history (b) even if I delete my browsing history, I will have to keep doing it after every time I visit a site, unless I browse in incognito mode (which I don't want to do).

**This question is:**

How do I disable the omnibox dropdown entirely, so that no matter what I type in the omnibox, it never shows a dropdown?

I want to disable the omnibox dropdown on **Mac** and on **Android**.